# Get Data from Database Where UserID is equal to value from asp:label

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Hello and Thanks for reading.

I have a form where users can Insert data into my database and at the same time, The users unique ID is store in the same table.

Here is the Code where I store the Unique in a label:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
string id = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
lblID.Text = id.ToString();
```

This is how my Database looks like / ID, Name, Email, Subject, Message, UserID /

Here is my Insert to Database Code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();

    string Name = txtName.Text;
    string Email = txtEmail.Text;
    string Subject = ddlSubject.SelectedValue;
    string Message = txtMessage.Text;
    string UniqueID = lblID.Text;

    string query = "INSERT INTO Ticket(Name, Email, Subject, Message, UserID)" + "Values('" + Name + "', '" + Email + "', '" + Subject + "', '" + Message + "', '" + UniqueID + "')";
    using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

What I'm having problems with is to Get data from the database where UserID = lblID.text.

as you can see in the code below I'm having a problem finding out what to write to load the data, where UserID = lblID.text.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();

                using (var GetName = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Ticket WHERE UserID=''", conn))
                using (SqlDataReader dr = GetName.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        lblGetData.Text = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Name"));
                    }
                }
```

Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line.

```
using (var GetName = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Ticket WHERE UserID=''", conn))
```

To

```
using (var GetName = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Ticket WHERE UserID='" + lblID.Text + "'", conn))
```

This query is prone to a sql injection attack though .. if you aren't sure of where the value is coming from, you should use a sql parameter to minimize the risk of sql injection.

Comment: Thanks so much, Worked Perfect.

Comment: "<strike>if you aren't sure of where the value is coming from,</strike> you should use a sql parameter to minimize the risk of sql injection." FTFY.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `lblID.Text` to the SQL query. Use this parameterized query to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

```
using (var GetName = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Ticket WHERE UserID = @UserID", conn))
{
    GetName.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", lblID.Text);
    using (SqlDataReader dr = GetName.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            lblGetData.Text = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Name"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var GetName = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Ticket WHERE UserID='" + lblID.Text + "'", conn))
```

Use this answer, I hope it helps.